# Problemas con “TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON OBJECT”

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy intentando mostrar un campo "nombre" que está en otra tabla conectadas entre si foráneamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la pimera tabla es la tabla de platoingredientes, donde tengo mis llaves foranemas, la segunda tabla que aprarece en el gif es de platos, donde tengo el id, el nombre y el valor. la tabla platoingredientes es la que tiene las llaves foráneas y la relacion es de que un platoingredientes tiene muchos platos.

platos migracion

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('platos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('nombre',50);
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

platoIngrediente migracion

```
public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('platoIngrediente', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('plato_id');
    $table->foreign('plato_id')->references('id')->on('platos');
    $table->unsignedInteger('ingrediente_id');
    $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('id')->on('ingredientes');
    $table->double('cantidad', 8, 2);
    $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ingrediente modelo

```
class Ingrediente extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = ['nombre','proveedor'];


}
```

plato modelo

```
class Plato extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'valor'];


    public function platoingrediente() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Plato');
}


}
```

platoingrediente modelo

```
class PlatoIngrediente extends Model
{
    public $table = "platoIngrediente";

    protected $fillable = ['plato_id', 'ingrediente_id', 'cantidad'];

    // UNO A MUCHOS
    public function platos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PlatoIngrediente', 'id','plato_id');
    }

        public function ingrediente(){
        return $this->belongsTo('ingrediente_id');
    }




}
```

este es el platoingrediente controller

```
public function index()
    {
      $platos = Plato::all();
      $ingredientes = Ingrediente::all();
      $platoingredientes = PlatoIngrediente::all();
      $platoids = PlatoIngrediente::with('platos')->get();
      return view('platoingrediente/index', compact('platos','ingredientes','platoingredientes','platoids'));
    }
```

esta es la vista

```
    <dd>Primero selecciona un plato en el sistema: </dd>
    <select name="plato_id" id="plato_id" class="form-control">
    <option selected>[ SELECCIONA UN PLATO ]</option>
     @foreach( $platoids as $platoid )
     @foreach( $platoingredientes as $platoingrediente )
    <option value="{{ $platoingrediente->id}}">{{ $platoid->platos->nombre }}</option>
   @endforeach
   @endforeach
  </select>
```

me sale el siguiente error

Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/food/resources/views/platoingrediente/index.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (0)

Comment: ya lo agregue a la publicación puedes verlo

Comment: Hay una redundancia innecesaria que no entiendo: ¿para qué obtener dos veces todos los modelos de `Platoingrediente`?

Comment: @Shaz es en lo que necesito ayuda. Dices eliminar la variable $platoingredientes en el controller y dejar solo $platoids?

Comment: antes de retornar la vista con las variables, si te salen adecuadamente? intenta hacer un dd($tuvariable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el controlador no necesitas obtener dos veces todos los modelos de `Platoingrediente`:

```
public function index()
{
    $platos = Plato::all();

    $ingredientes = Ingrediente::all();

    $platoids = PlatoIngrediente::with('platos')->get();

    return view('platoingrediente.index', compact('platos', 'ingredientes', 'platoids'));
}
```

En el modelo Platoingrediente, la relación debería llamarse `plato`, en singular, puesto que un platoingrediente tiene solo un plato relacionado, y se está relacionando en este caso con el modelo Plato, no con sí mismo (hasta donde entiendo según la base de datos):

```
public function plato(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Plato');
}
```

Y en la vista, llamar a la propiedad dinámica `plato` debería funcionar sin problema:

```
<dd>Primero selecciona un plato en el sistema: </dd>
  <select name="plato_id" id="plato_id" class="form-control">
    <option selected>[ SELECCIONA UN PLATO ]</option>

    @foreach( $platoids as $platoid )
      <option value="{{ $platoid->id}}">{{ $platoid->plato->nombre }}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: Funciona y me muestra los nombres correctamente, pero me salen repetidos amigo

Comment: Eso ya depende de cómo planteaste tu base de datos y la aplicación, creo que tienes un error importante de lógica por lo que estoy viendo.